# sass error when using :nth-child/:nth-of-type selectors

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I'm using sass in my current project and can't figure out why this won't compile :

```
.section {
    &:first-of-type {
        background: url("../img/misc/.jpg") center center no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        &--text {
            &--title {
                /*THIS WON'T COMPILE*/
            }
            &--subtitle {
                /*THIS WON'T COMPILE*/
            }
            &--subscribe {
                &--input {
                    /*THIS WON'T COMPILE*/
                }
                &--button {
                    /*THIS WON'T COMPILE*/
                }
            }
        }
    }
    &:nth-of-type(2) {
        &--text {
            &--title {
                /*THIS WON'T COMPILE*/
            }
            &--paragraph {
                /*THIS WON'T COMPILE*/
            }
       }
   }
   }
```

I'm getting this error : 
Invalid parent selector for "&--text": "Home stylesheet .section:nth-of-type(2)"

Here is my html:

```
<section class="section"> <!-- Cover section -->
            <div class="section--text">
                <h1 class="section--text--title">
                    Main title
                </h1>
                <p class="section--text--subtitle">
                    Some text
                </p>
                <div class="section--text--subscribe">
                    <input class="section--text--subscribe--input" type="email" placeholder="Your email">
                    <button class="section--text--subscribe--button">button</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="section"> <!-- Problem section -->
            <img src="img/ipad.jpg" alt="App screenshot">
            <div class="section--text">
                <h2 class="section--text--title">
                     Title
                </h2>
                <p class="section--text--paragraph">
                    Some text
                </p>
            </div>
         </section>
```

Can't I apply css rules to pseudo-selectors'children using nesting? What am I missing here?

Many thanks!

Comment: It would compile to something like: `.section:first-of-type--text`, whereas I assume you want something like `.section:first-of-type .section--text`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm aiming for! So I changed my sass for:
   `.section:first-of-type {
        .section--text {
            // some css
           &--title {
               //some css
           }
        }
    }`

(I shortened the code so I could fit it into the comment section, but hopefully you see what I mean?)

But it's still not working. I don't get it.
It's compiling to this :
`.section:first-of-type .section--text {//some css}`
`.section:first-of-type .section--text--title {//some css}`
etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the use of & to nest selectors. Your first nested selector will compile to (if it could) `.section:first-of-type --text`. To use your children classes you need to include the full class name (including the . selector). This should work fine:

```
.section {
    &:first-of-type {
        background: url("../img/misc/.jpg") center center no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        &.section--text {
            &.section--text--title {
                /*THIS WON'T COMPILE*/
            }
            &.section--text--subtitle {
                /*THIS WON'T COMPILE*/
            }
            &.section--text--subscribe {
                &.section--text--subscribe--input {
                    /*THIS WON'T COMPILE*/
                }
                &.section--text--subscribe--button {
                    /*THIS WON'T COMPILE*/
                }
            }
        }
    }
    &:nth-of-type(2) {
        &.section--text {
            &.section--text--title {
                /*THIS WON'T COMPILE*/
            }
            &.section--text--paragraph {
                /*THIS WON'T COMPILE*/
            }
       }
   }
```

}

The '&' works similarly to a space in CSS. More at:

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector

Comment: Tried it, it does compile, but still can't see my css reflected on the browser. I commented above on the last changes I made.
And yes, I'm fairly new to that nesting thing, I do get confused sometimes :)

Comment: Fixed it so it will work in the browser, my bad (typo) What are you expecting to happen? Your compiled code in the comment above looks fine

Comment: What I mean is, what do you want your compiled code to be?